# where on LINQ query

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, where-clause

I have the next code:

```
b.Text = myDataContext.purchases.Count().ToString();
```

the `"b"` is `label` that i have on aspx page.

I want to add to the code : where items.main == true , like i have here:

```
        var bla = from items in myDataContext.items
                   where items.main == true
                   select items;
```

How can i do that on the :     `b.Text = myDataContext.purchases.Count().ToString();`

i have table : `items` with column itemId and column main (bit).

and table: `purchase`.

on purchase i have column `itemId` (with relationship)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an overload of `Count()` that takes a predicate (filter); and the `== true` is redundant, so if the `main` is part of the *purchase*:

```
b.Text = myDataContext.purchases.Count(p => p.main).ToString();
```

With the edit, you will need to join, either through a helper member:

```
b.Text = myDataContext.purchases.Count(p => p.item.main).ToString();
```

Or manually:

```
  b.Text = (from p in myDataContext.purchases
            join i in myDataContext.items on p.itemId equals i.itemId
            where i.main
            select p).Count().ToString();
```

Comment: Gravell - thanks, i've posted the question without important details. i edited it now... your answer still relevant ?

Comment: I think it's should be like that :
 b.Text = myDataContext.purchases.Count(purchase => purchase.item.main).ToString();

Comment: @Bside the middle version above, then?

Comment: Yep, i thought i wrote somthing else on the last comment.. but i wrote the same like Rob ... thank you all !